# In bash, can test -e look for a file with a semi-variable name using *?

Tags: terminal, bash

I have an if then looking for a certain set of files. They all start with lib, so I could either set an if then up for each one or I was hoping there's a way I can use an asterisk.

Here's what I have and what I tried.

```
 d=myfolder
 if [[ -e $d/lib* ]]; then
  mv /etc/launchd.conf $d/launchd.conf
 else
  2>/dev/null; true
 fi
```

so as you can see, if any of those lib files are present I want to move the launchd.conf file as well. but the asterisk isn't doing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man bash`

> ```
> [[ expression ]]
>       Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional 
>       expression expression.  Expressions  are composed  of  the primaries 
>       described below under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS. Word splitting and pathname
>       expansion are not performed on the words between the [[ and ]]; tilde 
>       expansion, parameter and variable  expansion,  arithmetic expansion, command 
>       substitution, process substitution, and quote removal are performed.
>       Conditional operators such as -f must be unquoted to be recognized as primaries.
> ```

Or in short, the pattern is not expanded.

A simple alternative could look like

```
if [[ $(echo $d/lib*) != "$d/lib*" ]]; then
    mv /etc/launchd.conf $d/launchd.conf
fi
```

Short explanation on how this works:

- `echo $d/lib*` expands to a list of library files if any are present, this list is not equal to `$d/lib*` (which doesn't get expanded) so the `mv` is executed
- OTOH if no library files are present, the echo returns the string `$d/lib*`, the `!=` evaluates to false and the `mv` is not executed

Comment: I'm attempting to implement the alternative you provided but it's not quite doing what I need. Also, I may need to clarify, I'm using the asterisk to append the file-name, not to find an executable. I'm going to attempt to explain what the alternative does to see if I'm understanding it right.

Comment: I may have misread your question but isn't your goal to see whether there are any files matching `$d/lib*`?

Comment: Sorry, I waited too long to add the end of my comment haha. 


the goal is to see if there are any files matching $d/lib... because there are multiple files that all start with lib but end in something else.
 Examples: libgenkit.dylib, libgenkitsa.dylib, libimckit.dylib, libimckitsa.dylib.

So, if any of those files are in the $d folder, I want to move launchd.conf. If they aren't, do nothing.

if the variable (myfolder) with /lib* attached is not the same as myfolder/lib* (thus, if that is true) then move launchd.conf.

Comment: Which is, if I didn't make a typo of some sort, what the alternative should do. `echo $d/lib*` expands to a list of library files if any are present, this list is not equal to `$d/lib*` (which doesn't get expanded) so the `mv` is executed. OTOH if no library files are present, the echo returns `$d/lib*`, the `!=` evaluates to false and the `mv` is not executed. At least that's how it did work here :-)

Comment: Patrix, thank you for the response. It did work, the issue I was running into was I didn't correctly escape the quotes since it's being run in a `do shell script` command in AppleScript.